# showing and hiding the closest element on hover not working

Tags: jquery

I have multiple elements in a page that look like this:

```
<div>
    <span class="content_video_wrapper_video_icon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="content_video_wrapper_video_text" style="display: none;">
        <a href="...">Go to video</a>
    </span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="content_video_wrapper_video_icon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="content_video_wrapper_video_text" style="display: none;">
        <a href="...">Go to video</a>
    </span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="content_video_wrapper_video_icon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="content_video_wrapper_video_text" style="display: none;">
        <a href="...">Go to video</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I'm using jquery to show and hide on hover the closest element that has the class `content_video_wrapper_video_text` like so:

```
$(".content_video_wrapper_video_icon").each((i, el) => {
    $(el).hover(
        function() {
            $(this).closest(".content_video_wrapper_video_text").show()
        },
        function() {
            $(this).closest(".content_video_wrapper_video_text").hide()
        }
    )
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `closest` traverses up, not down, so the text item is not found. Would it matter if the icon and text spans were swapped?

Comment: @PaulT. I just swapped them and tried, didn't work. Sorry.

Comment: You could likely try the original code, but inside the handler change to: `$(this).closest('div').find(".content_video_wrapper_video_text").show()` should do it. Then apply the same for the hide.

Comment: @PaulT. Thanks Paul, that worked perfectly. Perhaps you could reply your comment to my post so I could choose it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `closest` traverses upwards, try with the code changes below:
(gets the closest div, and then find the desired element)

```
$(".content_video_wrapper_video_icon").each((i, el) => {
    $(el).hover(
        function() {
         //   $(this).closest(".content_video_wrapper_video_text").show()
            $(this).closest('div').find(".content_video_wrapper_video_text").show()
        },
        function() {
         //   $(this).closest(".content_video_wrapper_video_text").hide()
            $(this).closest('div').find(".content_video_wrapper_video_text").hide()
        }
    )
})
```